# Propertygrid: create custom property definition based on Margin target property

Tags: wpf, margin, propertygrid, wpf-extended-toolkit

I'm using the Extended WPF Toolkit's PropertyGrid. For the margin target property I would like to divide it from (0,0,0,0) to four separate fields with words or arrows, similar how it is in Visual Studio. My xaml looks like this:

```
            <extToolkit:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="Margin"/>
```

Current visual appearance:

[image: Current visual appearance]

Desired visual appearance:

[image: Desired visual appearance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked, but something easy you can do is setting the `IsExpandable` property to `true`, like so...

```
<extToolkit:PropertyDefinition TargetProperties="Margin" IsExpandable="true" />
```

That forces the PropertyGrid to expand out the object at that property.

However, if you want to do the editor the way you have it, you have to create a custom editor for that specific property.  You do that by associating your own templates for the editor.  Since it looks like something that may be reusable, I would design that as a control, then use that control as the editor.